# for looping 2 foreach

Tags: angularjs

Lets say I have two array of objects: **obj** and **obj2**

```
obj = [
   {"id": 0,"name": "foo","is_editable":true},
   {"id": 1,"name": "bar","is_editable":true},
   {"id": 2,"name": "app","is_editable":true}
]

obj2 = [
   {"id": 0},
   {"id": 2}
]
```

and I need to make the attribute **`is_editable = false`**
if the obj's id is in obj2

I have here my code, it works fine but I feel uncomfortable with my logic.

```
angular.forEach(data, function(obj) {
    obj.is_checker = false;
    angular.forEach(data2, function(obj2) {
        if (obj2.id === obj.id)
            obj.is_checker = true;
    });
});
```

Is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will def need some loops, but you can do this with plain old JS.

```
obj.map(function(item) { 
  obj2.map(function(item2) {
    if(item.id === item2.id) {
       item.is_editable = false;
    }
  })
})
```

If you wanna use angular to accomplish it, use pretty much the same logic.

```
angular.forEach(obj, function(item) {
    angular.forEach(obj2, function(item2) {
        if (item.id === item2.id)
            obj.is_editable = false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
obj.map(function(o){ 
   o.is_editable = obj2.some(function(c){ return c.id === o.id }); 
   return o;  
});
```

I would use `some` function to find whether or not the item is editable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had tried it and saw that it still loops just like foreach. so logic is still the same. But the return c.id === o.id overrides the value(last loop will be the value). I think i will choose my first logic ^_^ thanks again man